# iOS7's subview trimmed if out of parent view bounds

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I've rumbled through new UI info from apple - didn't help.

Now let the code and the screenshots show you the problem i've ran into.
To ensure that is not my buggy code, i've created a new project, with a single file - a UIViewController that has a tableView inside id. the delegates are set.

I do the following:

```
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 3;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return 3;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"UITableViewCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row];
    // Configure the cell...

    UIView * redView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -10, 100, 20)];
    redView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [cell addSubview:redView];

    return cell;
}
```

The table view is set on Grouped.
Lets run it on iOS 6:
[image]

Duh ofcourse, the Y origin is negative! 
Yes, it is, and this is the result I am trying to achieve.
Lets see what it shows on iOS 7:
[image]

Hint: that doesn't occur if we add redView to a normal UIView.

Another hint: if i set tableView's background color blue, the gray lines between sections would be blue, not gray (as a demonstration that the gray is not a set header).
Another hint: same goes for ipad.

Why in iOS 7 it cuts everything that goes out of bounds? Please help!

Comment: have you tried setting cell's `clipsToBounds` property to NO?

Comment: yes.. It didn't work, but thank you for the hint.

Answer (score 8):

It's because iOS 7 introduced some changes to the view hierarchy of UITableViewCells.

It used to be `UITableViewCell view -> contentView`.

Now it's more like `UITableViewCell view -> scrollView -> contentView`.

The solution is to set `clipsToBounds = NO` on the scrollView (which is set to YES by default). And the way to achieve that is through the `superview` property.

So basically in iOS6 and prior, to allow content to spill out of the cell bounds, you would do:

```
self.clipsToBounds = NO;                        //cell's view
self.contentView.clipsToBounds = NO;            //contentView
```

In iOS7 you have to also prevent the scrollview from not clipping so you'd do something like:

```
self.clipsToBounds = NO;                        //cell's view
self.contentView.clipsToBounds = NO;            //contentView
self.contentView.superview.clipsToBounds = NO;  //scrollView
```

And the backwards compatible solution I use is:

```
self.clipsToBounds = NO;
self.contentView.clipsToBounds = NO;
if ([self.contentView.superview isKindOfClass:[NSClassFromString(@"UITableViewCellScrollView") class]]) self.contentView.superview.clipsToBounds = NO;
```

Keep in mind this is Hacky™ and if the view hierarchy changes again in iOS 8, you might be in trouble. Unfortunately it seems Apple doesn't want us to spill content out of UITableViewCells so AFAIK this is the only workable solution.

Answer (score 2):

The following will fix it:

`cell.layer.masksToBounds = NO`

However, it will probably break something else, e.g. cell animations.

The problem you are having is caused by the fact that cells just don't support drawing content out of their bounds (actually, using subviews that extend the bounds of their superview is always a hacky solution).

The best advice is to redesign and avoid such funcionality at all.

Another solution could be to add the same view to the bottom of the previous cell or just add them as a subview of `UITableView` directly.

Comment: masktobounds didn't work at all, tried it both in custom cell class init method and in cellforrow tableView datasource method... 

I'm trying to follow your best advice and do it properly via headerforsection datasource method. But still waiting maybe somebody will come up with a solution for the described situation...

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that the contents are actually trimmed in a `masksToBounds`-sense, but instead that the views are covered by the other (opaque) cells. You could try to fix it by changing the order ("z-Index") of the `UITableView`'s subviews, using `bringSubviewToFront:` and similar methods whenever a cell appears to ensure that the cell closest to the bottom edge of the screen is the frontmost view of all the cells.

Comment: i've tried many fixes considering that this is the problem and didn't work. Thank you for your time, though!

Comment: @Theo you identified the problem right, but unfortunately `bringSubviewToFront` doesn't fix it. It only brings the subview in front within the contentView of the cell and not the entire tableView. Meaning, the  UITableViewCell covering the cell still remains in front